# echo all array except where array is null

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to echo out an array within a while statement, however, the results also include some columns from the database which may or may not be null.

Is it possible to echo all array where value is not null? I can't edit the mysql query as I need this to be dynamic as some of the columns may be used by another user.

My table contains around 20 columns, some are populated some aren't.

My code:

**PHP**

```
<?php 
     while($row = $mysqli_fetch_array($uploads)){
          print_r(!is_null($row));
     }
?>
```

**Expected Output**

`Firstname: John`

`Lastname: Test`

`Age: 15`

**Current Output**

1

Any help would be great, apologies for the lack of code.

Comment: `!is_null($row)` put this an a if statement and then print it

Comment: `$row` in that loop can't be `null`

Answer (score 1):

Many possible ways. Here's one example: You could [filter out](http://docs.php.net/array_filter) the null elements and then print $row

```
while($row = $mysqli_fetch_array($uploads)) {
    $row = array_filter($row); // 1
    // or 2: $row = array_filter($row, 'strlen');

    echo join(', ', $row), "\r\n";
}
```

1. this will type-cast each element to boolean and any keep those elements that evaluate to truthy. This might filter more elements than you'd like, see [Converting to boolean](http://docs.php.net/language.types.boolean#language.types.boolean.casting)
2. but you can tell aray_filter how to decide whether an element is in or out. In this case the *return value* of the function you give as the second parameter with be cast to boolean and checked. Using `strlen` an empy string and/or anything that get's cast to an empty string (like NULL) will result in `0`->`false`->filtered out.